# How to overwrite the db url on jar run command

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ucanaccess

I am using invalid jdbc connection and mentioned in app properties.But I am trying to overwrite that, on that time of running JAR file.

```
java -jar proj.jar --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:ucanaccess:db.accdb;
```

note, jar and db are same location. I dont want to place jar and db in different locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like :
Method 1: Using system properties

```
java -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:ucanaccess:db.accdb -jar proj.jar
```

Method 2: Using environment variables

Set jdbc connection url as SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL environment variable.

windows:

```
set SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:ucanaccess:db.accdb
java -jar proj.jar
```

Mac/Linux:

```
export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:ucanaccess:db.accdb
java -jar proj.jar
```

Comment: thank you. for quick response. working.
little change in your answer is,
java -Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:ucanaccess://./db.accdb -jar proj.jar

Comment: np, yeah I basically copied the string you provided in the question.